# Draw Charts side by side with gwt-visualization

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

i'm using the java gwt-visualization API in verison 1.1.2. I trie to add more than one Chart to a Flowpanel in order to display them Side-by-Side, but they are always displayed below each other.

Do you know a way to display them side by side? thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is the Area, large enough to display both chart's without a Scroll bar? Else the flowpanel will display them under each otehr.

You can assign a with to the Flowpanel, witch is as large as the width of both Flow Panel. However in this case you can use a  [Horizontal Panel](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwHorizontalPanel). This way your chart's are alowys side by side, but might overflow.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution by overwriting the css class `.gwt-viz-container` with :

```
    .gwt-viz-container {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
    }
```